# How to validate during training in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to validate my model every 5000 steps. The validation is based on another pre-trained model to validate the training model. The first 5000 steps goes fine, no errors. And the validation goes fine. However, when forwarding the 5001 step. An error comes up: `ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback): OOM when allocating tensor with shape[22,32,256,256]`. The tensor OOM is somewhere in the training model graph instead of the validation pre-trained model. I guess this is due to the pre-trained model used for validation is not released?

I'm wondering the right way to validate the training model during training. Am I doing something wrong? Someone tell me the right way to validate during training? Thanks a lot!

Here's the simplified code:

```
with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    try:
        for step in range(STEP_START, TRAINING_STEPS):
            def should(freq):
                return freq > 0 and ((step + 1) % freq == 0 or step == TRAINING_STEPS - 1)

            fetches = {
                'train': model.train,
                'global_step': model.incr_global_step,
                'update_ops': model.update_ops,
            }

            results = sess.run(fetches)

            if should(args.validation_freq):
                psnr, ssim = validation_psnr_ssim.evaluation(isTest=0, CHECKPOINT_DIR=MODEL_SAVE_PATH,num=args.validation_num)
                acd = validation_acd.evaluation()
                mean_wer, mean_wer_norm = validation_wer.evaluation()
```

Comment: Are you sure the methods you call during evaluation are not constructing any new operations?

Comment: @y.selivonchyk The evaluation model and code is based on Keras using tensorflow backend. New operations may be constructed during evaluation to build evaluation graph. And I guess these operations remains after evaluation. That's why OOM happened. So I'm looking for a method to clean up evaluation operations and tensors. These are my guess. I'm not sure whether it is correct.

Comment: The code looks pure tensorflow (not keras) to me. I would start to from running evaluation code only multiple times (commenting the training part out), to make sure that it does not leak memory. In the worst case you can always save/restore your model after each validation.